# Selecting a data attribute value with a space or a certain character

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, custom-data-attribute

I'm trying to select a data attributes value that has a space or a certain character in it but it doesn't like it very much. Below is the code that I have working for one worded attribute values.

```
$('div[data-roomtype='+$(this).data('roomtype')+']').animate({opacity:0.1},100);
```

And I have also put together a very simplified fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/Tse6k/2/) of what I'm hoping to achieve. Is there an easy solution to this? Any help or advice would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Quote the value in the selector:

```
// ------------------v -------------------------------v
$('div[data-roomtype="' + $(this).data('roomtype') + '"]'). ...
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/Tse6k/3/

Comment: in case of concating two values to the single data-attribute ?